# Rust/Diesel: How to query and insert into postgres tables which have uuid

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have the following schema generated by Diesel:

```
table! {
user (id) {
    id -> Uuid,
    name -> Text
}
```

and the associated model

```
use diesel::{
    self,
    Queryable,
    Insertable,
};
use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::sql_types::Uuid;
use super::schema::user;

#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub name: String,
}

impl User {

    pub fn get(id: i32, connection: &PgConnection) -> Vec<User> {
        user::table.load::<User>(connection).unwrap()
    }
}
```

I get an error when I try to compile this which says:

```
21 |         user::table.load::<User>(connection).unwrap()                                                                                                                              
   |                         ^^^^ the trait `diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Uuid, diesel::pg::Pg>` is not implemented for `diesel::sql_types::Uuid`
```

If I try to insert I get a similar error saying that `Expression` is not implemented.

Could this be a problem with my dependencies or something I may have forgotten to add to the model?

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.0-rc.1"
serde = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde_json = "1.0"
diesel = { version = "1.0.0", features = ["postgres", "uuid"] }
r2d2 = "*"
r2d2-diesel = "*"

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "0.4.0-rc.1"
default-features = false
features = ["json", "diesel_postgres_pool", "uuid"]
```

Answer (score 19):

Just spent a lot of time with this problem as well. It looks like as of Diesel 1.4.5, you can add the latest version of `uuid`, but you have to specify the `uuidv07` feature on Diesel.

Your `Cargo.toml` should look something like this:

```
uuid = { version = "0.8.2", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["chrono", "postgres", "r2d2", "uuidv07"] }
```

Source: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/2348

Note: Also, like @canab said, the `Uuid` type on the struct should be from the `uuid` library, not the Diesel SQL type.

Answer (score 12):

The type in the struct needs to be a Rust type rather than a SQL type, specifically `Uuid` from the [uuid crate](https://docs.rs/crate/uuid) (in Diesel 1.3, only version 0.6 is supported by Diesel). In the code from the question, the `Uuid` is expanded to a `diesel::sql_types::Uuid`

```
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: uuid::Uuid,
    pub name: String,
}
```

Comment: After reading just about everything I could find online, this issue was resolved for me finally by fixing `uuid` to version 0.6. Thank you for pointing this out, it wasn't made obvious anywhere else.

Comment: In my case I just change from `uuid` to `uuidv07` on features for diesel

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is the `use diesel::sql_types::Uuid;` where has a trait that is not required so instead you can use purely a uuid crate. So you can use on one side the diesel feature "uuid" to generate the entity and the uuid crate to declare the struct:
So you will have the following:

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "2.1.0", features = ["postgres", "uuid"] }
uuid = "1.8.0"
... rest of dependencies
```

And in the struct

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
use uuid::Uuid;

#[derive(Queryable, Selectable)]
#[diesel(table_name = crate::schema::user)]
#[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::pg::Pg))]
pub struct User {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub topic: String,
    pub body: String,
    pub read: bool,
}
```